# Kubernetes - Why does selector field fail to validate for Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

Using Kubernetes 1.2.4, why does my below [Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) definition (redis.yaml) cause the following error?

```
$ kubectl apply -f redis.yaml
error validating "redis.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field name for v1beta1.LabelSelector; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

**redis.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: kubernetes/redis:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Selector directives in Deployments [require](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements) you to use a sub-field of either `matchLabels` or `matchExpressions`, so in my case I need to make use of `matchLabels`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: kubernetes/redis:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: What if the `apiVersion` we use is `apps/v1`?

Answer (score 16):

The `selector` field of a [`v1beta1.DeploymentSpec`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_deploymentspec) object is of type [`v1beta1.LabelSelector`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_labelselector) rather than just a plain map. So, you can either add the label under the `matchLabels` field of the `selector`:

**redis-with-matchLabels.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: kubernetes/redis:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Or leave the `LabelSelector` out of the `DeploymentSpec`, in which case it will match the labels from the `PodSpec`:

**redis-podSpec-labels.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: kubernetes/redis:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

See the [Selector section](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#selector) of the Deployment docs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the purpose of `.spec.selector`? I'm a bit confused by the documentation, especially the paragraph "If specified, `.spec.selector` must match `.spec.template.metadata.labels` [...]. If `.spec.selector` is unspecified, `.spec.selector.matchLabels` will be defaulted to `.spec.template.metadata.labels`". What's the purpose of having `.spec.selector` if it needs to match `.spec.selector.matchLabels` but also defaults to it if left unspecified?

Comment: I meant to say `.spec.template.metadata.labels` instead of `.spec.selector.matchLabels` in my last sentence, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if one accidentally changes the **apiVersion** to anything other than "v1beta1".

The schema is critical and will be checked. However, if the content is correct and the schema wrong, it might still work.